# How read length of server file(file is located on server)

Tags: java, spring-boot, file, url, file-handling

File is availebal on server my motive is to read file length,I have access of server

```
File filevar = new File("http://k8s-den-...../doc/get/path/pratik/94960_popo.txt");
           
           System.out.println("The length of the file is : "+filevar.length());
```

Output is 0. How to deal with this problem and value inside filevar is http:\k8s-den-.....\doc\get\path\pratik\94960_popo.txt

Comment: That looks like a URL. Are you sure that there's a file with that name?

Comment: HttpURLConnection conn = null; 
    URL url = new URL("http://k8s-den-...../doc/get/path/pratik/2022/0/25/7/94960_popo.txt"); 
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        System.out.println( conn.getContentLengthLong());
                output is 18

Comment: In above comment is showing file is availeble and content also.But why i am not able  to put server file on our filevar

Comment: `File` represents files on a file system, e.g. a local disk or a mounted network drive. Your "file" is an HTTP resource.

Comment: URL dir_url = ClassLoader.getSystemResource("http........url");
    File dir = new File(dir_url.toURI());       &&&&                                      
                        URL default = new URL("http://k8s-...url");
    File file = new File(default.toURI());................BOTH not work for me